# Target tag inside parent on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent element:

```
.product-container
```

Then, inside it, I have a `<p>` element, which is styled in css via:

```
.product-container p
```

Now, I need to apply some style to this `<p>`, when `.product-container` is hovered. But this does not work:

`.product-container:hover .product-container p`

So, is there a way to target this `<p>` on parent hover via css, without applying class or id to the `<p>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
.product-container:hover p
```

instead of

```
.product-container:hover .product-container p
```